# Undefined Array in constructor with TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

My code creates a dispatcher from constructor ColorDispatcher. After window.onload,  dispatcher.hoverOutHandler is regularly called after 1.5 sec. when changeBGColor called, the typeError described in the title shows; However I really cannot figure out why.

```
var ColorDispatcher = function() {
  this.changeColorTimerID = 0;
  this.rgbColorArray = new Array(0, 0, 0);
};

ColorDispatcher.prototype = {
  hoverOutHandler: function() {
    this.changeColorTimerID = window.setInterval(this.changeBGColor, 1500);
  },
  changeBGColor: function() {
    //something went wrong here.
    alert(this.rgbColorArray[0]);
  },

};
var dispatcher = new ColorDispatcher();
window.onload = dispatcher.hoverOutHandler();
```

Comment: `window.onload = function () { dispatcher.hoverOutHandler(); }`

Comment: @hsfzxjy: `window`'s `load` event is almost never the answer to any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
 this.changeColorTimerID = window.setInterval(this.changeBGColor.bind(this),1500);
```

setInterval called the function on the window scope therefor the array wasn't found. With `.bind` you can bind a function to a scope (in this case `this`).

Comment: Obvious duplicates don't need answers, just close-votes (and comments if appropriate).

Comment: Thank you so much Angelo; it works fine.